# Notepad++ - regex : replace first occurrence of a characters group in each line

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Someone would know the regex expression can be used (in notepad++) in order to replace the first occurence of a characters group in each line?

eg:

```
abcdefg//ijkl//m.
qsdflkj//sdqlmkf//jqsmdl.
```

to

```
abcdefg\\ijkl//m.
qsdflkj\\sdqlmkf//jqsmdl.
```

so replace `//` by `\\` in each line, but only the first occurence of , not the next.

If regex can't achieve it, is there another method with notepad. If not, I will code a program to split line and do the job, but need more time.

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: `^(.*?)(\/\/)(.*)` with `gm` modifiers and substitution of `$1\\$3`

Answer (score 11):

Enter this regex in `Find what` field

```
(.*?)//(.*)
```

Enter this in `Replace with` field

```
$1\\$2
```

Select `Regular expression` in `Search Mode` and Uncheck `. matches newline`

Comment: Isn't this just a copy/rewording of my comment?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it before I post this. Should I delete this answer ?

Comment: Great !! works perfectly. Big thanks to Youssef13 and so @ctwheels if he is the original author....

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^/]+\K//`
- Replace with: `\\\\`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  [^/]+         : 1 or more any character that is not a slash
  \K            : forget all we have seen until this position
  //            : 2 slashes
```

**Replacement:**

```
\\\\     : 2 backslashes, each one must be escaped
```

**Result for given example:**

```
abcdefg\\ijkl//m.
qsdflkj\\sdqlmkf//jqsmdl.
```